# How to make selenium web driver wait till my firefox plugin is finished executing

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, firefox-addon

I am using Selenium web driver in JAVA to test a functionality. In parallel I have developed a firefox add on to do another functionality. I am facing 500 internal server error when Selenium tries to access the next page (lets say - when i click login button). I think this is becuase the plugin has not yet finished its functionality yet. The plugin tries to access multiple urls in parallel. Now how can i make my selenium web driver to wait for my firefox plugin to finish executing. I tried Thread.sleep(time). But the time limit varies and I dont want to waste much time in giving sleep. How can i make teh web driver wait till the plugin finishes executing ?

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    /* Add plugin to the profile*/
    WebDriver firefoxDriver = new FirefoxDriver( profile );
    firefoxDriver.navigate().to("URL");
    WebElement username = firefoxDriver.findElement(By.id("User"));
    WebElement password = firefoxDriver.findElement(By.id("Password"));
    username.clear();
    password.clear();
    username.sendKeys("userid");
    password.sendKeys("passwd");
    firefoxDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    firefoxDriver.findElement(By.className("log-on-btn")).click();
```

This is the sample code which I am using to test the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Please use :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

It will wait / pause webdriver action to run till your set time in seconds.
You can set seconds , minutes as per your need.

Comment: Yes. I tried that option. But the problem is the plugin takes a varied amount of time(2-3 mins) to finish its functionality.  In this scenario I don't want all of my pages to wait for 2-3 mins before executing as this plugin needs to be executed for every page I am visiting in a subdomain.

Comment: But I think we can not separate wait fucntion like for plugin and site pages.

Comment: Better you share your created code so I can check and give some solution.

Comment: I was thinking of an option where I can insert an element to the page source using the plugin after it finishes its functinality and I can trigger the seleneium driver to wait for the particular element in teh page soruce so that it can proceed accordingly

Comment: As per your code , it looks you are doing login activity to page. So where is plugin call code?

Comment: The plugin/addon code is independent which triggers automatically when my page is getting loaded in the browser. I will be able to just add the plugin/addon to the firefox profile before it boots through selenium.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67756/discussion-between-googytech-and-helping-hands).